# split string in php using regex

Tags: php, regex, arrays, string, preg-split

how can I split this string:

```
|^^^*|^^^*|^^^*|^^^*|^^^*|myvalue^nao^nao^nao*|myvalue^nao^nao^nao*|myvalue^nao^nao^nao*|^^^*|^^^*|^^^*|^^^*|^^^*|^^^*|^^^*|^^^*|^^^*|^^^*|^^^*|^^^*
```

so I can only get the value "mayvalue".

For the moment, I'm using:

```
$text = preg_split("/[^\|(*.?)\^$]/", $other);
```

But it returns `myvalue^nao`

Any ideas?

Comment: are you only trying to get the words myvalue? if so you can use a word boundry /bmyvalue/b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get all "myvalue" and other strings placed after `|` and before `^` in an array, `$matches[1]`:

```
$text = preg_match_all("/\|(.*?)\^.*?\^.*?\^.*?\*/", $other, $matches);
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I'm looking for at the moment.It works great.

Answer (score 2):

You could split twice, once on `|` and again on `^`; if your big string is in `$input`, then:

```
$pipes = preg_split('/\|/', $input);
$want  = preg_split('/\^/', $pipes[6]);
```

Then `$want[0]` has what you're after. This would probably be easier than trying to come up with one regex to split with.

Demo: http://ideone.com/pxvay

Since shesek hasn't come back I'll include their suggested approach. You can also use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) twice since you're working with simple delimiters:

```
$pipes = explode('|', $input);
$want  = explode('^', $pipes[6]);
```

and again `$want[0]` has what you're looking for.

And a demo of this approach: http://ideone.com/SwGEH

Comment: He's better off using `explode()` if its just a plain string... no need for a regex

Comment: @shesek: You should expand that into an answer, PHP isn't my native language so I was just going with what was already there.

Comment: Thank you for you time my friend, with your answer I could get closer to what I wanted.